# Why didn't the greeting get picked up by SO's filter?

Tags: support, questions

Out of curiosity: according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) question and Jeff's answer, `h(e|a)y(?![a-z])|` should be automatically removed. But, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278354/how-to-put-content-of-binary-file-in-a-string-in-c) question, it hasn't been. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The regex is applied to the raw Markdown of the post as Jeff described it, so the fact that the OP bolded the text as `**Hey**` caused it not to match due to the asterisks.

Comment: Should it be considered a bug then? Because whether we agree that greetings should be removed or not, the filter's not doing its job.

Comment: Technically, yes. I don't know if it's worthwhile to make it *too* complex just to try and catch every case though, as ultimately people can edit whatever falls through the cracks. It's mostly just meant to reduce the frequency with which that kind of stuff appears.

Comment: @szczurcio Not really a bug, more of completely out-of-scope for what it does. Trying to parse infinite variants of something someone typed when they realize they just encountered a regex is .. futile. That thinking (in how we scope matches) _occasionally_ leads to someone inadvertently getting through checks because there wasn't a match, but we're talking about a _very_ small minority. The cost of running anything more expensive just isn't worth it.